# sprite sheets in native app (NOT cocos2d)

Tags: ios, plist, sprite, sprite-sheet

Short Q. Mostly to get me help that can point me in the right direction.

I am having problem finding help on how to use and implement spritesheets (insted of loads of seperate icon.png) in a 'normal' native app with storyboard.

All I have found so far is how to do it in cocos2d for games. And I am aware that I have to implement it all programmatically and not through storyboard.

So far all I have is a spriteSheet.png and a generated spriteSheet.plist tnx to http://www.Zwoptex.com

any help or pointers are appreciated

tnx